# Import data into mysql from JSON file using Python Code

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-3.x

How to **import data into mysql** from the given JSON file in Python? I'm getting error as

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/risha/PycharmProjects/Test/JSON_TEST.py", line 24, in
> >     
> >         con = pymysql.connect(host = '127.0.0.1',user = 'root',passwd = '',db = 'test',port ='3306')   File
> >     "C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql__init__.py",
> >     line 90, in Connect
> >         return Connection(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
> >     line 704, in **init**
> >         self.connect()   File "C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
> >     line 964, in connect
> >         self.host_info = "socket %s:%d" % (self.host, self.port) TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

```
import pymysql

import os
import json

# read JSON file which is in the next parent folder
file = 'C://Users//risha//PycharmProjects//Test//video.json'
json_data= open(file).read()
json_obj = json.loads(json_data)


# do validation and checks before insert
def validate_string(val):
   if val != None:
        if type(val) is int:
            #for x in val:
            #   print(x)
            return str(val).encode('utf-8')
        else:
            return val


# connect to MySQL
con = pymysql.connect(host = '127.0.0.1',user = 'root',passwd = '',db = 'test',port ='3306')
cursor = con.cursor()


# parse json data to SQL insert
for i, item in enumerate(json_obj):
    person = validate_string(item.get("person", None))
    year = validate_string(item.get("year", None))
    company = validate_string(item.get("company", None))

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO testp (person,  year,   company) VALUES (%s,    %s, %s)", (person,  year,   company))
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: did you try anything?'

Comment: Yes, but getting error with SQL connection

Comment: can you please provide your code so that we can see what went wrong?

Comment: Please have look at my code https://ideone.com/tFXoYi

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Edited , please check now in question section

Comment: try port=3306 without quotes

Comment: Now it is saying pymysql.err.InternalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'test'")

Comment: have you created database called 'test'?

Comment: No I haven't created any database

Comment: then it will definitely show that error. you need to manually create that test database and then run your program